# erlcloud- dynamodb2, manage counters (update_item)

Tags: amazon-web-services, erlang, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having a bit of a hard time finding an answer to the problem- how can i update a value in aws ddb2 using erlang and erlcloud library.

i am managing a table for different counters, and i neet to add one (i++), to one of the records.

in the doc they suggest

```
{ok, Item} = 
    erlcloud_ddb2:update_item( 
      <<"Thread">>, <br>
      [{<<"ForumName">>, {s, <<"Amazon DynamoDB">>}}, 
       {<<"Subject">>, {s, <<"How do I update multiple items?">>}}],
      <<"set LastPostedBy = :val1">>,
      [{condition_expression, <<"LastPostedBy = :val2">>},
       {expression_attribute_values,
        [{<<":val1">>, <<"alice@example.com">>},
         {<<":val2">>, <<"fred@example.com">>}]},
       {return_values, all_new}]),
```

i guess that what i need to do is use ADD statement as used in this example, but i don't know any more than that.

i can see in their code:

```
dynamize_action(add) ->
    {<<"Action">>, <<"ADD">>};
```

but i'm not sure how the `UpdatesOrExpression` value should be written

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

after deep diving to erlcloud library, this is the answer for my question:

```
erlcloud_ddb2:update_item(<<"table_name">>,
 [{"hash_col_name",
 {n,"hash_col_value"}}],
 {"field_name", 1, add},
 [] ,AWSConfig).
```

for zeroing the index:

```
erlcloud_ddb2:update_item(<<"table_name">>,
 [{"hash_col_name",
 {n,"hash_col_value"}}],
 {"field_name", delete},
 [] ,AWSConfig).
```